# Issue using exponents in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to setup an equation using sympy. But the use of exponents seems to be throwing an error:

```
import sympy
from sympy import init_printing

init_printing(use_unicode=True)


E0, V0, B0, dB0, V  = sympy.symbols('E0 V0 B0 dB0 V')

E0 + 9*V0*B0/16 * (
  [(V0/V)^2/3 - 1 ]^3 * dB0 + \
  [(V0/V)^2/3 - 1 ]^2 * [6-4*(V0/V)^(2/3)] \
)
```

Returns the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'Mul' and 'int'
```

Comment: Exponentiation is denoted by the `**` operator in python, `^` is for bitwise xor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, the exponent operator is not `^`, but `**` instead. In scypy too (as can be seen in this example about series in the docs: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/tutorial.html#series-expansion)